# Using dataSet.ReadXml when the server is continuously pushing xml

Tags: c#, xml, httpwebrequest

I'm connecting (using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse) to a server that is continuously pushing XML data. what I need is to read the data and store them into a dataset online.
Currently this is what I do:

```
        HttpWebRequest httpRequest;
        string url = "something";
        System.Data.DataSet dataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
        httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pass");
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender1, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        HttpWebResponse response;
        int count = -1;
        string read = string.Empty;
        response = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
        do
        {
            count = response.GetResponseStream().Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            read += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf, 0, count);
            dataSet.ReadXml(new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(read)));
        } while (response.GetResponseStream().CanRead && count != 0);
```

but since in every loop a part of the xml data is received, the ReadXml function would cause an exception.
What can I do to get this problem solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "continuously" you mean without ever ending, then you should not use a DataSet, since this is not designed to be used like this.

That being said, the problem you're having is that the network data you're reading can be arbitrarily cut to pieces, so that you don't even get valid XML fragments back. Instead, you should use an `XmlReader` on the response stream and read from that, since this will put the pieces back together.

However, directly passing this into `ReadXml()` will not do the trick because it would never stop. So what you'll probably end up with is some simple code reading the parsed fragments from the `XmlReader`, and insert these manually into whatever data storage you want.

Comment: You're right, I think finally I'll have to do this and I hate it actually.

Comment: Well, you might want to look into alternatives for the MS .NET XML classes in order to get streaming evaluation support. I believe that [VTD-XML](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/) and [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) have that kind of support built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the line

```
dataSet.ReadXml(new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(read)));
```

outside the do-while loop, and then having the while-clause only evaluate count:

```
while (count > 0);
```

It could also be helpful to get the instance of the response stream outside the loop. There might be unforseen consequences by having the `GetResponseStream()` call on every loop.

Comment: Yes, but we're not getting out of the loop. It will be unreachable.

Comment: Just added a few more suggestions to my initial answer

Comment: No change, the real problem is what Lucero talked about. I think I have to forget about using dataset.ReadXml()

Comment: Yeah - i missed the crucial part about "continously" - glad you got it figured out ;-)